# Após achar a resposta da pergunta não termina a aplicação

Tags: c

A questão é que, a primeira pergunta seria se é réptil e depois se tem casco, a resposta será tartaruga, mas mesmo já aparecendo a resposta o algoritmo continua, antes ele encerrava após achar a resposta e não sei o que fiz que agora não encerra (Isso vale para todos).

No caso, essa é a minha única dúvida, porquê o programa não encerra após achar a resposta de cada? Sou iniciante então não conheço nenhum comando avançado.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    char respma, respave, respreptil;
    char respcasco, respcarn;
    char respvoa, resprap, resptrop;
    char respqua, respbi, responi;

    printf("\nO animal e reptil(s/n)? ");
    respreptil = getche();

    if (respreptil=='s') {
        printf("\nTem casco(s/n)? ");

        respcasco = getche();
        if(respcasco=='s'){
            printf("\nE uma tartaruga");
        }
        else {
            printf("\nE carnivoro(s/n)? ");
            respcarn = getche();

            if(respcarn=='s'){
                printf("\nE um crocodilo");
            }
            else{
                printf("\nE uma cobra");
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\nO animal e uma ave(s/n)? ");
    respave = getche();

    if (respave=='s') {
        printf("\nVoa(s/n)? ");

        respvoa = getche();
        if(respvoa=='s') {
            printf("\nE de rapina(s/n)? ");

            resprap = getche();
            if(resprap=='s'){
                printf("\nE uma aguia");
            }
            else{
                printf("\nE um pato");
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("\nE tropical(s/n)? ");

            resptrop = getche();
            if(resptrop=='s'){
                printf("\nE um avestruz");
            }
            else{
                printf("\nE um pinguim");
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\nO animal e um mamifero(s/n)? ");
    respma=getche();

    if(respma=='s') {
        printf("\nE quadrupede(s/n)? ");

        respqua=getche();
        if(respqua=='s') {
            printf("\nE carnivoro(s/n)? ");

            respcarn=getche();
            if(respcarn=='s'){
                printf("\nE um leao");
            }
            else{
                printf("\nE um cavalo");
            }
        }
    }

    getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

para encerrar o programa após achar alguma solução é necessário interromper seu fluxo de alguma maneira, finalizando a sua execução ou  redirecionando ao fim dele.

Eu aconselho usar o comando *return*, esse comando irá finalizar a sua função e retorna algum valor, no seu caso, irá finalizar a função principal *main*, terminando a sua aplicação.

Para fazer isso, basta inserir o *return* após exibir a resposta correta.

```c
if(respcarn=='s'){
    printf("\nE um crocodilo\n");
    return 0; // Finalizando o programa
}
```

**OBS:** O *return 0* é usado para avisar que o programa terminou corretamente.

Aqui está o programa completo, com algumas alterações a mais, pois a função *getche()* não era reconhecida.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    char respma, respave, respreptil;
    char respcasco, respcarn;
    char respvoa, resprap, resptrop;
    char respqua, respbi, responi;

    printf("\nO animal e reptil(s/n)? ");
    respreptil = getchar();
    getchar();


    if (respreptil=='s') {
        printf("\nTem casco(s/n)? ");

        respcasco = getchar();
        getchar();
        if(respcasco=='s'){
            printf("\nE uma tartaruga\n");
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            printf("\nE carnivoro(s/n)? ");
            respcarn = getchar();
            getchar();

            if(respcarn=='s'){
                printf("\nE um crocodilo\n");
                return 0;
            }
            else{
                printf("\nE uma cobra\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\nO animal e uma ave(s/n)? ");
    respave = getchar();
    getchar();

    if (respave=='s') {
        printf("\nVoa(s/n)? ");

        respvoa = getchar();
        getchar();
        if(respvoa=='s') {
            printf("\nE de rapina(s/n)? ");

            resprap = getchar();
            getchar();
            if(resprap=='s'){
                printf("\nE uma aguia\n");
                return 0;
            }
            else{
                printf("\nE um pato\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("\nE tropical(s/n)? ");

            resptrop = getchar();
            getchar();
            if(resptrop=='s'){
                printf("\nE um avestruz\n");
                return 0;
            }
            else{
                printf("\nE um pinguim\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\nO animal e um mamifero(s/n)? ");
    respma=getchar();
    getchar();

    if(respma=='s') {
        printf("\nE quadrupede(s/n)? ");

        respqua=getchar();
        getchar();
        if(respqua=='s') {
            printf("\nE carnivoro(s/n)? ");

            respcarn=getchar();
            getchar();
            if(respcarn=='s'){
                printf("\nE um leao\n");
                return 0;
            }
            else{
                printf("\nE um cavalo\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    getchar();
}
```

**OBS:** Usei dois *getchar()* seguidos para pegar o caracter '\n' (quebra de linha) que ficava sobrando no buffer após dar um enter.